# Kendo Grid command buttons

Tags: kendo-grid

I cannot figure out how to implement a delete button in a Kendo grid.

If I am reading the docs correctly, this is what I'm supposed to do:

```
vm.masterGrid.dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport:{
        destroy: function(e) {
            console.log(e);
            vm.removePackages(e.data);
        },
    }
});

vm.masterGrid.gridOptions = {
    columns: [
        { command: "destroy", title: "Remove" },
    ],
```

It never hits the console.log

Here is an example of the destroy command:

http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/editing
(1/3 down page **Edit this example**] can't link directly to the code for some reason)

I am able to completely delete the transport, it is has no effect at all; the delete happens anyway.

```
destroy: {
    url: crudServiceBaseUrl + "/Products/Destroy",
    dataType: "jsonp"
},
```

So I guess it happens by magic. Magic I can't reproduce in my own code.

Answer (score 0):

First, in the demo you linked, if you delete the transport.destroy configuration, the row will still be removed from the Grid when you click the the Delete button.  The transport.destroy is not invoked until you Save Changes.
When you do click Save Changes and then refresh the page/grid, you will find that the row was not deleted in the back-end.
If you leave the destroy config in place, the row will be gone on page refresh.

Second, depending on how you have set up the other transport configs that you have not shown (read, update, create), this bit of documented functionality may be the problem(http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#configuration-transport.destroy)

> All transport actions (read, update, create, destroy) must be defined in the same way, e.g. as functions or as objects. Mixing the different configuration alternatives is not possible.

I would guess that you have some of the transport as objects(probably read) and when the destroy is a function, it is probably just failing silently...would have to step through the kendo code to know for sure.

Comment: I have no need for many of the CRUD functions. In some cases, it's just READ and maybe PUT. Kendo really seems to insist that you do everything The Kendo Way. I've got buttons and controls all over my page for interacting with the data (such as api calls: "Check All", "Refresh Data") that need to trigger non-CRUD Kendo changes, but Kendo doesn't like to expose hooks to itself.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write your own delete code, then just add this line in grid code.

```
 remove: function(e){
   debugger;
   console.log("Debugger Hits :)");
 }
```

Just edit your above given link and change to this:

```
 $("#grid").kendoGrid({
                        dataSource: dataSource,
                        navigatable: true,
                        pageable: true,
                        height: 550,
                        remove: function(e){
                            debugger;
                            console.log("Debugger Hits :)");
                        },
                        toolbar: ["create", "save", "cancel"],
                        columns: [
                            "ProductName",
                            { field: "UnitPrice", title: "Unit Price", format: "{0:c}", width: 120 },
                            { field: "UnitsInStock", title: "Units In Stock", width: 120 },
                            { field: "Discontinued", width: 120 },
                            { command: "destroy", title: "&nbsp;", width: 150 }],
                        editable: true
                    });
```

---

Or, Instead Of Using Kendo's Default Delete Button, Why Don't You Use Your Own Delete Button Like This ?

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
                        dataSource: dataSource,
                        navigatable: true,
                        pageable: true,
                        height: 550,                        
                        toolbar: ["create", "save", "cancel"],
                        columns: [
                            "ProductName",
                            { field: "UnitPrice", title: "Unit Price", format: "{0:c}", width: 120 },
                            { field: "UnitsInStock", title: "Units In Stock", width: 120 },
                            { field: "Discontinued", width: 120 },
                            { title: "&nbsp;", template: "<button onClick='customEditor()'>Custom Delete Button</button>", width: 150 }],
                        editable: true
                    });
                });

              function customEditor(){
               debugger;
                console.log("Yes, I Am Custom Delete Button");
              }
```

Hope it works for you.